# How to fix css issue for this image slide?

Tags: html, css

When one image changes into another each time it moves a bit bottom and right and comes back after the animation until to the next image change. It's simple slideshow. Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <transition-group name='fade' tag='div'>
      <div v-for="n in [currentN]" :key='n'>
        <img :src="Image" />
      </div>
    </transition-group>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100%
}

img {
  height:600px;
  width:100%
}
```

What is wrong and how can fix that image change animation issue and keep image full width of the screen and height 600px all the time without changing its position?

I found it in jsfiddle few days ago and tried to make changes on it.

Comment: Could you edit your question and use code snippet so we can have better understanding of the problem? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I found it in jsfiddle few days ago and tries to make changes on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommended Solution**

Giving static number for the width of `img` will solve the problem. Change from `100%` to your preferred width in `px`, like this:

```
img{
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}
```

**Alternate solution:**

```
body{
  margin:0px;
}
```

This prevents your image to flow off the grid and enable you to use `100%` on the image tag as you did initially. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L5y2hqua/

**Code Snippet**

```js
new Vue({
    el: 'image-slider',
    data: {
        images: ['http://i.imgur.com/vYdoAKu.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/PUD9HQL.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/Lfv18Sb.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/tmVJtna.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/ZfFAkWZ.jpg'],
        currentNumber: 0,
        timer: null
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.startRotation();
    },

    methods: {
        startRotation: function() {
            this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 3000);
        },


        next: function() {
            this.currentNumber += 1
        },
        prev: function() {
            this.currentNumber -= 1
        }
    },
    
    computed: {
     currentImage: function() {
       return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentNumber) % this.images.length];
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100%;
}

img {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
<image-slider>
    
    <transition-group name='fade' tag='div'>
      <div
       v-for="number in [currentNumber]"
       :key='number'
       >
         <img
             :src="currentImage"
             />
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</image-slider>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, but if it's needed to make it the full width of the screen?

Comment: @NewTechLover, Checkout the **Alternate Solution**